# Facing an issue in BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

While I am adding data source to BAM showing an error like  org.postgresql.Driver

My database is PostgreSQL. I am trying to connect to that database.

Can anyone solve my problem?

Comment: Can you clarify your question ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include Postgre JDBC driver into repository/components/lib directory in BAM server. Then you need to specify details in master-datasources.xml located in repository/conf/datasources directory. Theoretically then everything should work. But there may be some SQL syntax incompatibilities with sample toolboxes. If so you may need to change the SQL, used in both Hive scripts and dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the postgre jar to the $BAM_HOME/repository/components/lib directory as mentioned in maninda's response, you can create the data-source via wso2 management console. Go to configure -> DataSources and fill the form with the required fields. You also can add the datasource via the master-datasource.xml, which creates the datasource for in the server start-up.

Sample datasource is given below. You have to change he respective url, driver class, username and password for your postgre data-source.

```
<datasource>
           <name>MY_DATA_SOURCE</name>
           <description>The datasource used for analyzer data</description>
           <definition type="RDBMS">
               <configuration>
                   <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/samples/TEST_DB;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</url>
                   <username>root</username>
                   <password>root</password>
                   <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                   <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                   <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                   <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                   <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                   <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
               </configuration>
           </definition>
```

Comment: ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.core.DataSourceRepository} -  Error establishing data source connection: org.postgresql.Driver
org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.common.DataSourceException: Error establishing data source connection: org.postgresql.Driver
when i am clicking on test connection it is not showing healty,so i am facing the above error.

Comment: i added poatgres jar file in lib also.test connection is not showing healty.